# How to run the jgraph example?

Tags: jgraph

I recently have to use Jgraph to build a topu of our IoT net, however, I have no idea of how to run the Jgraph example.Any one can help me? The link of Jgraph in github is here:https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late but if you're still interested... once you have added the [project](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx) in your ide, make sure the src and examples packages are both marked as source folders and run the GraphEditor class in (jgraphx/examples/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/GraphEditor.java)